# Join one value from an array to each result row

Tags: postgresql

I want to select data from a table and assign one value from an array to each result row.

e.g. given a table with the following product data

```
product
-------
car
bike
elephant
```

and an array like this

```
string_to_array('0.8, 0.6, 0.9', ',')
```

I want to get a table like this

```
product | value
---------------
bike        0.8
car         0.6
elephant    0.9
```

Any ideas how to easily solve this?

Something like this

```
WITH data_table AS (
  SELECT
      pr.id
    , pr.name
  FROM
    products pr
  ORDER BY pr.id
  LIMIT 20
)
SELECT 
    data_table.name
  , multipliers[row_number() over(order by data_table.id)]::numeric * data_table.id AS multiplied_value
 FROM 
     data_table
   , string_to_array('0.8, 0.6, 0.9, 0.65, 0.34, 0.67, 0.85, 0.12, 0.45, 0.76, 0.68, 0.98, 1.23, 0.69, 0.86, 1.11, 0.75, 1.02, 0.3, 0.79', ',') multipliers
 ORDER BY multiplied_value DESC
 LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please?

Comment: What is the assign logic? You can update your table, or you have to solve with sql select. You can solve it out of postgre too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the order of the rows should be defined by sorting by name, you can use the following:

```
select name, n[rn] as value
from (
   select name, row_number() over (order by name) as rn,
          string_to_array('0.8, 0.6, 0.9', ',') as n
   from the_table
) t
```

Comment: I think my problem is that I want to order the end result differently from the sort order for determining the row numbers. In the above extended example, I want to sort by the result of the multiplication of the array value with a value in the table.

Comment: Actually both your solution and my solution above seem to work fine. Just didn't see it after staring at the screen for too long.

Comment: @JosephTura: you can sort the result of my query by any column you like